# This is the .htaccess code in WordPress. Can someone explain how it works?

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, .htaccess

This is the .htaccess code for permalinks in WordPress. I don't understand how this works. Can someone explain?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I googled and found out that `-f` and `-d` part means to give real directories and files higher priority.

But then what are `^index\.php$ - [L]` and `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` ?

How does WordPress process categories, tags, pages, and etc. with just this?

Does it happen internally? If so, I'm interested in learning how to do it in PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`^index\.php$ - [L]` prevents requests for `index.php` from being rewritten, to avoid an unnecessary file system check.  If the request is for `index.php` the directive does nothing `-` and stops processing rules `[L]`.

This block is all one rule, and it says that if it is not a real file and not a real directory, reroute the request to `index.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

index.php itself interprets the URL that was requested by the client (PHP can see the requested URL using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and it calls the correct code for rendering the page the user requested.

Comment: I noticed that wordpress redirects domain.com/index.php to domain.com.

If I wanted to do something like that in PHP, should I just use the header function? I'm wondering is there's a better way (search engine friendly? more efficient?) to do it.

Comment: I don't see any reason a 301 redirect from the Header function wouldn't be appropriate.  You could tweak your mod_rewrite settings to do a quick 301 redirect in theory, but it isn't going to make a huge difference either way.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`: isn't it redundant, since `index.php` is indeed a real file (thus hitting `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`)?

Comment: @matpop If you rewrite an url, has the requested filename changed?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When at first `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` is executed, don't we get an existing filename? If so, wouldn't then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` return false in the second iteration? I don't see an infinite loop fix, at best an optimization. What am I missing? Thanks for your help

Comment: @matpop I agree with you. Since index.php is a real file and it exists in the root, what is the need for RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] to avoid internal loops? I agree there won't be a loop, I tested and haven't noticed a problem. For a billion $ company like wordpress should not have this simple mistake, I landed on this question just to look for an answer for this, anyone catches something we are missing?

Comment: @Tarik Exactly. The only case of infinite loop is when the file index.php isn't really there. If we assume that the file exists, the only effect of the first rewrite rule is that the engine does not check at all whether the requested resource is a filename in the second iteration (or even in the first iteration if index.php was requested deliberately). Is all this of any real use? Judge by yourself!

Comment: @Tarik, I agree with you, this is not about infinite loops. What it does do though, is prevent an unnecessary file system check on the subsequent run through. This improves performance, keeping the file system checks to two for **every page request** rather than three. A regex is quicker than polling the file system.

Comment: Another point is that it wouldn't loop infinitely, even if `index.php` didn't exist, because mod_rewrite only restarts processing if the URL changes. So no infinite loop would occur here.

Comment: Why not just use `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`? I'm testing it and it's not giving me any error. Are the other lines really necessary?

Comment: hi there Kevin - many thanks for the great answer. You helped me alot! BTW: i want to do this for using to redirect HTTP to HTTPs with https://www.example.com and https://example.com/ and http://example.com - what kind of htaccess do i need to run ? Look forward to hear from you