# String automatically replaced in URL, how do I stop this?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, .htaccess

Any time I have the word "index" in any part of the URL, the server or CMS automatically changes it to `http:/domain.com` (yes there is only one forward slash.)  For instance, typing in the the URL in the address bar: `domain.com/foo/barindex/xyz.html` will automatically change to `domain.com/foo/barhttp:/domain.com/xyz.html`.

I am using WordPress and Apache.  I have checked .htaccess, to no avail.  In essence, as String automatically replaced in URL, how do I stop this?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# allow all except those indicated here
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>
```

Comment: Post the content of Your .htaccess

Comment: don't put in in the comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: See, maybe this can help you understand

[Config htaccess][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061880/this-is-the-htaccess-code-in-wordpress-i-dont-understand-how-it-works-can-so

Comment: Your .htaccess does not explain this behavior. Is your WordPress installed in a sub-folder? And if so, have you also checked any .htaccess files in the parent folders?

Answer (score 0):

Probably something with another Apache config file which is changing all occurrences of 'index'. To find what files might be effecting your request, ssh into your server and run;

```
httpd -v
```

and look for `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

Find and open this file and look for any other rewrite rules, or inclusions of other config files.

You could even talk to your hosting company to get this figured out as if you haven't set up this rewrite I'm sure they would be aware of it and where it lies.

EDIT: 
Standard Wordpress Rewrite Rules;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Not worries. Did you end up finding the problem?

Comment: We are in talks with the hosting company.  I will report back on our findings!

Comment: The hosting company said it had something to do with the .htaccess file, which I included above.  TBH, I don't see how what is happening is based on the .htaccess file, as none of Rewrites appear to suggest such a change.

Comment: This is not correct. I've included the correct/standard wordpress rewrites which as you can see mirror yours. Either go back to your hosting company and tell them this is not correct, or find other (if there are) included conf files and check them out. 

Maybe another thing try going to the backend and updating your permalink settings. Just change them to something, save, and then change them back.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I don't know what happened, or who did it, but the problem no longer happens.  Perhaps it was something on there end afterall.