# wordpress index.php problems

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My web host moved me to a new server

- http://www.doctorwhoworld.co.uk does not load
- edited the .htaccess file still is not working
- I have disabled all plugins it still will not work

Here is my .htaccess content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Please can someone help me so question a will work again and not to the index.html page

Comment: Can you paste the .htaccess contents here?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: I am all the other pages need to be for example http://www.doctorwhoworld.co.uk/doctors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061880/this-is-the-htaccess-code-in-wordpress-can-someone-explain-how-it-works

Comment: Please add your .htaccess.

Comment: Do You Change all urls from database also?

Comment: @ahearne I've added your htaccess content that you pasted into a comment into your question. In future, you are able to edit your own question to add this sort of info when needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have a redirect loop from

```
http://www.doctorwhoworld.net/
```

to

```
http://www.doctorwhoworld.net/index
```

Ask your hosting provider to check if they did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick question, can you change the url in WordPress for the site. If you can do that I would try and see if it is pointing to domain.com/ or domain.com/index.php that could also be a common issue, try that and let me know.

Comment: it would seem from disabling custom permalinks plugin that the index.php resurfaces - I have tried to amend the permalinks to show http://www.doctorwhoworld.co.uk/doctors but it will not let me - can anyone enlight on how to get this because I do not like the prologue/doctors and it's messes up some of the links I have done I just want it to be doctors at the end of .co.uk for example; thanks

Comment: As you will see per the screenshots - http://www.doctorwhoworld.co.uk/Images/permalinks-a.jpg  then the other with b.jpg as it will not let me add more than one URL I click on custom structure but it reverts back to /reference/bbcdvds when I want it to be just bbcdvds